# How to javascript filter only accessible menus

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, frontend

If there is a specific sub-menu key value using a one-dimensional array, the specific sub-menu must be grouped into a higher-level menu group to express a menu that the user can access.

However, my stupid brain can only search up to the parent element.

- Data Structure for Menus:

```
const menus = [
    {
      key: "/a",
      label: "a",
    },
    {
      key: "/b",
      label: "b",
    },
    {
      key: "/c",
      label: "c",
      icon: null,
      children: [
        {
          key: "/c-1",
          label: "c-1",
        },
        {
          key: "/c-2",
          label: "c-2",
        },
        {
          key: "/c-3",
          label: "c-3",
        },
        {
          key: "/c-4",
          label: "c-4",
        },
        {
          key: "/c-5",
          label: "c-5",
        },
        {
          key: "/c-6",
          label: "c-6",
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      key: "/d",
     label: "d",
      icon: null,
      children: [
        {
          key: "/d-1",
          label: "d-1",
        },
        {
          key: "/d-2",
          label: "d-2",
        },
      ],
     
    },
    {
      key: "/e",
      label: "e",
    },
    {
      key: "/f",
      label: "f",
      icon: null,
      children: [
        {
          key: "/f-1",
          label: "f-1",
        },
        {
          key: "/f-2",
          label: "f-2",
        },
        {
          key: "/f-3",
          label: "f-3",
        },
      ],

    },
    {
      key: "/g",
      label: "g",
      icon: null,
      children: [
        {
          key: "/g-1",
          label: "g-1",
        },
        {
          key: "/g-2",
          label: "g-2",
        },
        {
          key: "/g-3",
          label: "g-3",
        },
        {
          key: "/g-4",
          label: "g-4",
        },
      ],

    },
  ];
```

- for example (This structure cannot be changed.):

```
const accessibleMenus = ['a','b-1','b-2','f'];
```

I want to express a menu that is accessible to users. help.:

```
a

b

 ㄴ> b-1
 ㄴ> b-2

f
```

```
const test = menus.filter(({ label }, i) => label === accessibleMenus[i]);
```

but ...

It is difficult to access child elements and filter only the desired menu.